# Why the alert() is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML with input forms and button:

```
<input id="nameField" type="text">
<input id="submitBtn" type="button" value="Submit">
```

And script:

```
$(function() {
    var name = $('#nameField').val();

    var data = {
        name: name
    }

    $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
        alert(data.name);
    });
});
```

Enter text into the field and click button. But the alert is the empty and there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you initialize `data` as soon as the document is ready, long before the user enters the text.

You can do that :

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
       var name = $('#nameField').val();
       var data = {
          name: name
       };
       alert(data.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
var name = $('#nameField').val();

var data = {
    name: name
}
    alert(data.name);

});
```

});

You need the current value of the field when he clicked the node, not when the pages load.
You can declare the "data" object as global (window.data) variable and the just change the "name" value in the "click" function.